# Add a progress tracking mechanism to hadoop MapReduce Cleanup

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Let's say I'm using cleanup() functions in Hadoop MapReduce. How would I add a progress tracking mechanism inside it, let's say in percentage complete, to display it in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implementation of the cleanup() of the [Mapper.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.21/mapreduce/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.java) class.

When a Hadoop job is run from the command prompt, the following is printed on the console.

11/10/31 18:15:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
11/10/31 18:16:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
11/10/31 18:16:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
11/10/31 18:16:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%

The code for the above is in the [Job.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.21/mapreduce/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.java) class.

```
  String report = 
    (" map " + StringUtils.formatPercent(mapProgress(), 0)+
        " reduce " + 
        StringUtils.formatPercent(reduceProgress(), 0));
  if (!report.equals(lastReport)) {
    LOG.info(report);
    lastReport = report;
  }
```

Mapper.cleanup() code has to be modified to print the progress to the console and jar file built. I don't think there is OOB support for the cleanup in Hadoop.